# Problems installing Xilinx need help urgently

Tags: xilinx

Please I need help installing Xilinx this is driving me completely insane I'm trying for months now.

Here's the thing I do the instalation but then when it's suppose to appear a windor to purchase a license NOTHING APPEARS! Why? How can I install a license. Also after installing HOW CAN I RUN XILINX FROM TERMINAL?

Please someone help me step-by-step. I try to go to settings64.sh BUT PERMISSION DENIED. And when I can go there NOTHING HAPPENS

I NEED HELP PLEASE this is like the 3rd time i ask here for help and I'm starting to feel desperate.

Explain this to me like I had no brain...

Comment: Try `sh settings64.sh`

Comment: Where? like in what directory? or that doesn't matter and I can do it from "home". Sorry this is the first time I'm using ubuntu

Comment: In the directory where `settings64.sh` is located. Or use the full path to run from any dir

Comment: pedro@pedro-VirtualBox:~/Documents/14.7/ISE_DS$ sh settings64.sh
settings64.sh: 12: [: settings64.sh: unexpected operator
. /home/pedro/Documents/14.7/ISE_DS/common/.settings64.sh /home/pedro/Documents/14.7/ISE_DS/common
. /home/pedro/Documents/14.7/ISE_DS/EDK/.settings64.sh /home/pedro/Documents/14.7/ISE_DS/EDK
. /home/pedro/Documents/14.7/ISE_DS/PlanAhead/.settings64.sh /home/pedro/Documents/14.7/ISE_DS/PlanAhead
. /home/pedro/Documents/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/.settings64.sh /home/pedro/Documents/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE

Comment: this is what appears...